# pd.Series.agg showing weird behaviour with geometric mean

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I was trying to find the geometric and harmonic mean of a Pandas series using pandas when I came across some odd behavior. I initially defined a couple of simple functions and tested it on a dummy series. I got the error below:

```
def gmean(x):
    a = np.log(x)
    return np.exp(a.mean())
def hmean(x):
    return 1/(1/x).mean()
s=pd.Series([1,3,9])
s.agg([hmean, gmean])
```

This gave the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/miniconda3/envs/dsbasic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py:430, in Apply.agg_list_like(self)
    429 try:
--> 430     concatenated = concat(results, keys=keys, axis=1, sort=False)
    431 except TypeError as err:
    432     # we are concatting non-NDFrame objects,
    433     # e.g. a list of scalars

File ~/miniconda3/envs/dsbasic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py:331, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    326     warnings.warn(
    327         msg.format(arguments=_format_argument_list(allow_args)),
    328         FutureWarning,
    329         stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
    330     )
--> 331 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/dsbasic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py:368, in concat(objs, axis, join, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    159 """
    160 Concatenate pandas objects along a particular axis.
    161 
   (...)
    366 1   3   4
    367 """
--> 368 op = _Concatenator(
    369     objs,
    370     axis=axis,
    371     ignore_index=ignore_index,
    372     join=join,
    373     keys=keys,
    374     levels=levels,
    375     names=names,
    376     verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
    377     copy=copy,
    378     sort=sort,
    379 )
    381 return op.get_result()

File ~/miniconda3/envs/dsbasic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py:458, in _Concatenator.__init__(self, objs, axis, join, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy, sort)
    454     msg = (
    455         f"cannot concatenate object of type '{type(obj)}'; "
    456         "only Series and DataFrame objs are valid"
    457     )
--> 458     raise TypeError(msg)
    460 ndims.add(obj.ndim)

TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[122], line 1
----> 1 s.agg([gmean, hmean])

File ~/miniconda3/envs/dsbasic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py:4605, in Series.aggregate(self, func, axis, *args, **kwargs)
   4602     func = dict(kwargs.items())
   4604 op = SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype=False, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
-> 4605 result = op.agg()
   4606 return result

File ~/miniconda3/envs/dsbasic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py:1108, in SeriesApply.agg(self)
   1107 def agg(self):
-> 1108     result = super().agg()
   1109     if result is None:
   1110         f = self.f

File ~/miniconda3/envs/dsbasic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py:172, in Apply.agg(self)
    169     return self.agg_dict_like()
    170 elif is_list_like(arg):
    171     # we require a list, but not a 'str'
--> 172     return self.agg_list_like()
    174 if callable(arg):
    175     f = com.get_cython_func(arg)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/dsbasic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py:438, in Apply.agg_list_like(self)
    436     result = Series(results, index=keys, name=obj.name)
    437     if is_nested_object(result):
--> 438         raise ValueError(
    439             "cannot combine transform and aggregation operations"
    440         ) from err
    441     return result
    442 else:
    443     # Concat uses the first index to determine the final indexing order.
    444     # The union of a shorter first index with the other indices causes
    445     # the index sorting to be different from the order of the aggregating
    446     # functions. Reindex if this is the case.

ValueError: cannot combine transform and aggregation operations
```

After a little digging, I saw that when using the gmean function with `pd.Series.agg`, it was returning the original series back, even though calling it directly seemed to work:

```
s.agg([gmean])
#       gmean
# 0     1.0
# 1     3.0
# 2     9.0

gmean(s)
# 3.0000000000000004
```

I thought there may be some bug in my code, so I found a scipy function that does geometric mean(It even has the same name). That function also had the same issue:

```
from scipy.stats import gmean
s.agg([gmean])
#       gmean
# 0     1.0
# 1     3.0
# 2     9.0
```

Funnily enough, `DataFrame.agg` and `DataFrameGroupBy.agg` don't have the same issues:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    a = ['alpha','beta'] * 5,
    x = np.random.rand(10)
))

test_df[['x']].agg(gmean)
# x    0.378187

test_df.groupby('a')['x'].agg(gmean)
# a
# alpha    0.498097
# beta     0.287143
# Name: x, dtype: float64
```

Am I missing something here? I can use the Dataframe version and solve my issue, but I want to know why this is breaking like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.agg.html):

> ### Series.agg(func=None, axis=0, *args, **kwargs)
>
> Aggregate using one or more operations over the specified axis.
>
> #### Parameters: **func**: *function, str, list or dict*
>
> Function to use for aggregating the data. **If a function, must either work when passed a Series or when passed to Series.apply.**

```py
def gmean(x):
    a = np.log(x.values)
    return np.exp(a.mean())

def hmean(x):
    return 1 / (1 / x.values).mean()

s = pd.Series([1, 3, 9])
```

will work because the functions are now assuming the input is a `pd.Series` object, which requires using the `.values` method to obtain the data as an array.

```py
>>> s
0    1
1    3
2    9
dtype: int64
>>> s.agg([gmean, hmean])
gmean    3.000000
hmean    2.076923
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Accepted. Thanks. It's still confusing behavior, but at least I know what to avoid